# mongodb date converting issue

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using mongoDB with morphia in java ,I am saving a value in date format

value before save : Wed Mar 14 03:09:23 IST 2012
      after save in mongo : ISODate("2012-03-13T21:39:23Z")

Mongo adding some number of hours when it save , Is there any way to save this value as it is in date format

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mongodb saves datetime as "UTC DateTime", which you can refer to the following link.

[Dates - MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates)

To use the date you stored, just convert it to you local time. you will get the original.

Comment: but problem occur when i search by date, let's say i am searching by '2012-03-14' then the particular record which is stored like ISODate("2012-03-13T21:39:23Z") is not in the search result.Should i convert '2012-03-14' to UTC before execute the query ?

Comment: sure, before query your database, you will need to convert to UTC if you use plain text to represent your date. otherwise, if you use java driver, you can just use the datetime object without conversion.

Comment: When trying to search for date-portion-only in your local timezone, matching the date value isn't going to cut it because a single date in your local TZ spans two dates in UTC.  Note that "search for date YYYY-MM-DD" really means "search for timestamp between YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00 and YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:59.999".  Unless you construct this timestamp range in your local TZ and convert both ends the range to UTC before querying, you will not get the right answer.