# MongoDB Dates with Java/Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, date, time, morphia

This might be related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063545/mongodb-date-converting-issue) but what happens to me is that when reading **Dates** using **Morphia** from a **MongoDB** instance on a server with a different timezone than my local machine it's like morphia automatically switches to my local timezone (hence it adds 2h).

Any way to just say "get what you read and do not convert"?

Comment: its always a case when you read date from different server. The safe way to do this is to read date as string, and then convert

Answer (score 0):

The Date object in Java uses [universal time (UTF)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) internally. You can also add a Java VM option `-Duser.timezone=UTC` which forces the Java runtime to report things in UTC which makes it easier for debugging etc.

When formatting a date for a user, you can use [setTimezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) in DateFormatter and everything else should work fine.